# What's the symbol behind Einstein's head?

Tags: energy, history, notation

What's the symbol called that's behind and to the right of Einstein's head in this picture? Bonus if you can tell me what the whole formula is!

[image: image of Einstein and formulas]

Comment: you are used to the E=mc**2 form of the formula, where m is the relativistic mass,  and do not recognize it when represented by using the behavior of the rest mass. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/conrel.html

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1092619/ (closed)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical symbol identification.

Comment: It's not something I feel strongly about, but I think the close votes are a bit unfair. The question is basically asking what the equation is, and that seems a fair question.

Comment: @JohnRennie Doesn't it not ask a specific physics question ? Just because it's related to physics doesn't mean it's fit for physics.se. Such questions are better asked on chat.

Comment: I concur with @JohnRennie here, this is a fair question to ask.

Comment: @Gaurav Funny you should direct me to chat when access to chat requires 20 reputation points and I have yet to reach that in this SE! People use the resources they have access to and to suggest that someone should use a resource they don't have access to as an alternative seems kind of ridiculous doesn't it?

Comment: @ShannonBuckland I'm really sorry that I failed to notice you didn't have enough rep to chat.

Comment: @DavidZ, I would like to request that my post be reopened and removed from [on hold] as the general consensus within the comments is that it is appropriate. The one comment that suggest this belongs in Math.SE is of great confusion for me considering the reciprocal response in Math.SE is exactly why it was posted here...

Comment: Continued... Math.SE said the question is appropriate in Physics.SE yet Physics.SE says it belongs in Math.SE. If both say it belongs in the other and neither say it belongs where it is then the only option left is purgatory and that option is completely counterproductive to the root purpose of StackExchange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [link to the Einstein archives online](http://alberteinstein.info/).  You will see the same cursive letter E used in his signature.

Comment: This seems more suited for a comment (to Goodies' post?) than an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Louis. I appreciate everyone's responses and feedback but I found the link you provided to be the most useful and pertinent to the root of my question. Thanks again to everyone for all the great feedback.

Comment: The answer does identify the symbol as a cursive $E$, so as far as I'm concerned it meets the criterion to be considered an answer.

Comment: I only intended to confirm what had already been posted in other comments by citing a proper reference.  I will accept the reputation points, with humility, since they now enable the comment privilege.  Thank you all for your patience, support and constructive criticism.

Answer (score 5):

The equation is that of the relativistic energy of a 'particle' with a nonzero mass.
$$
E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

The symbol itself I've never seen before. However, I think it's important to mention that $1/\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ is represented by $\gamma$ ($\text{gamma}$).

The factor $\gamma$ is often used in special relativity in Lorentz [Length Contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) and [Time Dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) (space and time contract with relativistic speed).

Comment: It's an E in cursive script.

Comment: Yes. Ignore the initial left swoop, and you'll see it.

Comment: Also worth noting that with a little algebra, you can show this formula is equivalent to $E^2 = m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2$, where $p = mv / \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$ is the relativistic momentum. So the formula is telling you the total energy in a given frame is a combination of the rest mass energy and energy due to motion in that frame.

Comment: By the way, on the blackboard, the symbol for the speed is really $q$, not $v$, see comments about Geschwindigkeit $q'$ here:

http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol4-doc/71